# Schedule tasks only in business days Celery

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

Is it possible to configure scheduling celery tasks to execute only during business days ( not in week days but in business days e.g by accessing a giving business days dataset for example ) using celery beat?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a crontab schedule and the `day_of_week` parameter:

```py
from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'businessdays': {
        'task': 'your_task_here',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week='1-5'),
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but I'm not looking to schedule my tasks during weekdays as I've mentionned in my post. I'm looking to schedule tasks in business days which are = basically weekdays - ( public holidays + bank holidays ). So, such a requirement can be imported via a dataset where to define your business holidays of the year.

Comment: @Anna, you can check it somewhere in task body, cause it would be quite complex task to set up crontab to follow custom calendar.